# which texts do you recommend to study mathematical logic ? 

Tags: lo.logic

I intend to study mathematical logic , my purpose is to get to Godel's incompleteness theorems

I haven't study any mathematical logic before

so what is the good text which I can use for this purpose ?

I search for a book give me the right picture , and good explanations

I will use it as self-study

Comment: This might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205518/what-is-the-prerequisite-knowledge-for-learning-godels-incompleteness-theorem/205882#205882

Comment: I think that a high-school student who is not already pretty sophisticated is better off asking at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest Cori and Lascar's "Mathematical logic", two small books ; the first book covers propositional calculus, Boole algebras and predicate calculus ; the second recursive functions, Gödel's theorems, set theory and the basics of model theory. I found the proofs precise, the examples nice.

Comment: does the text provide the complete proof of godel's theorems ?! or just the book mentioned with no proof ? 

Comment: My real goal is to study the proof of godel's theorems 

that's what i look for , so if the text don't prove the theorem ! that's not good ! 

is the text suitable to a high school student ?! 

Comment: The chapter 6 (1-4 is in book I and 5-8 in book II) is "Formalization of arithmetic, Gödel theorems", and ends with stating and proving the theorems. The proofs are short, but of course use many results detailed before.

The books are very progressive and start very low, but since I have no idea what a "high school student" knows, I can't assure you it's a perfect fit.

Comment: I studied geometry ,high school algebra , calculus " very good course " and I study abstract algebra and linear algebra now 

have general idea of logic 

____________

you said " the proof is short but use many results delaited before " 
do you mean that the proof is not complete ? or you mean that it's complete but he gave a nice proof who is shorter than the traditional one ? 



Comment: have you studied the subject from this text ? or you just know ? 

somebody recommended " logic for mathematicians " by Hamilton 

what do you this about this text ? 

Comment: what is the subject which the one have to study it before Godel's incomplteness theorems ?!! 

and are there other text which cover this topics and godel's incompletenss theorems only ? 

Comment: The proofs are complete if you have read what comes before: the theorems are deduced from other results stated and proved earlier. I haven't read Hamilton's book, so I can't comment on it.

I don't think it's reasonable to expect a text which will take you from exactly where you are to exactly where you want to be. All I can tell you is that the reference I gave you starts at a very reasonable level, and treats various subjects, including what you want. It comes with nice examples, interesting exercises (with solutions), and full proofs. I enjoyed learning about the subject reading it.

Comment: thank you 
Merci beacoup , tu es aide moi :) 

I think I'll use this text :))) 

thanks alot 

Comment: when i start studying the text , do you mind if I ask you in something which isn't obivous for me ? 

Comment: Mr, Julien Puydt , do you mind if you help me with the things which maybe difficult for me ? 

Comment: Just start reading and ask around if something stucks.

(Notice the comments of this question aren't the most suitable place)

Comment: yes , I will ask in a new question not here of course :)

Comment: i'm going to start from next tuesday after finishing my exams :) 

Comment: I suggest the math part of stackexchange. Take your time.

Answer (score 1):

MR0194311
Lyndon, Roger C.
Notes on logic. 
Van Nostrand Mathematical Studies, No. 6 D. Van Nostrand Co., Inc., Princeton, N.J.-Toronto, Ont.-London 1966 vi+97 pp.

This was by far the best introductory book when I studied logic (also by self-study) back
in 1970-s.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a huge fan of Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffreys, "Computability and Logic." The first-order logic part proper starts with the chapter "A precis of first-order logic: syntax," and the book can be begun there without any loss of continuity. (The previous chapters are a lengthy intro to computability theory; I found it helpful to return to those chapters after finishing the chapters on first-order logic.)

Alternatively, Richard Kaye's book "The mathematics of logic" is quite good; it takes you as far as Godel's Completeness Theorems, at which point it's easy to switch to something like Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffreys to cover the incompleteness theorems.

(And, for a nice preview of Godel to give you some motivation, this paper by Rosser (http://philpapers.org/rec/ROSAIE) is a wonderful exposition of the reasoning around Godel's incompleteness theorems, and further results.)